# Reason behind notation of $\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}$

Tags: calculus, notation, math-history

Why is the notation the way it is? Is there any history behind it, or any logic which I am not aware of?

Comment: The notation is very natural: $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx} \frac{d}{dx} =\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$

Comment: @azif006 So are we 'squaring' the 'd' in the numerator? And why aren't we 'squaring' the d in the denominator?

Comment: The reason we write the square of $dx$ as $dx^2$ instead of $d^2x^2$ is the same as the reason we write $\sin^2$ instead of $s^2i^2n^2$. It's because $dx$ is not the product of $d$ and $x$, it's a variable with a two-letter name.

Comment: @user14111 so why isn't it $\frac{dy^{2}}{dx^{2}}$?

Comment: The numerator $d^2f$ represents an operation, like log, square root, etc.  The square says take the operation twice.
If you go further in Calculus you'll encounter $\frac{d^2f}{dx dy}$, which means take the derivative relative to y first, then the derivative relative x.  For first semester Calculus courses your denominator, could be written $dxdx$

Comment: Please search on the website to see if your question has been answered before.  I bet this one has.  Duplicate questions are likely to be closed.

Comment: @KrrishGupta because $\frac{dy^2}{dx^2}$ means $\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dy}{dx}$, which is very different from $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{d}{dx} y$.

Comment: Okay one more question @nickalh: Like in exponentiation, we can raise any number to any real power, can we differentiate any number of times? For example, does $\frac{d^{1.5}y}{dx^{1.5}}$ have any meaning?

Comment: I have a B.S. in Math and have never fractional powers for derivatives.  They may exist somewhere but it's not in common usage at the undergraduate level.

Comment: Oh okay. thanks.

Comment: There are fractional derivatives, you can checkout the wikipedia page.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475016/leibniz-notation-for-high-order-derivatives/4831211#4831211

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2029072/26369

Answer (score 2):

Indeed this notation is not very natural. It is meant to be a shorthand of $\frac d{dx} \frac{dy}{dx}$. But since differentiation of quotients is not equal to the quotient of differentiation, a more logical notation might be
$$ \frac d{dx}\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\frac d{dx} dy}{dx} - \frac{dy \frac d{dx} dx}{(dx)^2}.$$ But this is just too long to write out. We regard $dx$ as a single entity, so $dx^2$ is short for $(dx)^2$ (i.e. $d$ has higher precedence than exponentiation, you can revise PEMDAS to P**D**EMDAS). And the $d^2 y$ is just there to remind you that it was $d \ dy$ on the numerator.

Answer (score 1):

A short answer to understand why the notation

$$
\frac{dy^2}{dx^2}
$$

would be bad to indicate the second derivative (of $y$ with respect to $x$) is that dimensions don't agree. The second derivative has dimensions of $[y]/[x]^2$ while the notation above has dimensions $[y]^2/[x]^2$ (which is wrong).

For a more detailed answer you can look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25102/why-is-the-2nd-derivative-written-as-frac-mathrm-d2y-mathrm-dx2) as noted by @Bumblebee.